# Split windows form to 4 window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

i hope any one can can help me , i use WPF to split the window to 4 window i built this code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Background="#feca00" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock FontSize="35" Foreground="#58290A" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap">4</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <GridSplitter ResizeDirection="Rows" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#58290A" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                BorderThickness="5">
            <TextBlock FontSize="25" Margin="20" Foreground="#FECA00" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap">3</TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#58290A" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                BorderThickness="5">
            <TextBlock FontSize="25" Margin="20" Foreground="#FECA00" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap">2</TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#58290A" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                BorderThickness="5">
            <TextBlock FontSize="25" Margin="20" Foreground="#FECA00" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap">1</TextBlock>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

i want to built this code by windows form not WPF .
In the same way split screen in WPF . 
I try to built it but don't find result can any one help me please .

Comment: Have you tried using the SplitContainer?

Comment: Yes , ican't find any thing

Comment: I would suggest updating your question with your win form code and describing how it currently works, and then asking a specific question about how you would like it to work. FYI, for something like this, a screenshot showing the desired behavior might also help, since it looks like you have a working example already.

Comment: You can use TableLayoutPanel control in winform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd like to welcome you to StackOverflow. Now, I'd like to point out that this is *not* a website where you can come to get someone else to do your work for you. *You* are expected to come here with a *specific* problem and *clearly* explain what that problem is and show the code that have got a problem with... it is *not* appropriate to come here and say '*How do you do this, because I don't know how to?*'. Please find more information in the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the StackOverflow Help Center.

Now to move onto your answer... bearing in mind what I just said, it would *not* be appropriate for me to provide you with a full, working example. As such, I'd like to highlight what @MilanRavel said about the `TableLayoutPanel`. As WinForms has no `Grid` element to rearrange your child UI controls for you, you'll have to make do with the [`TableLayoutPanel` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which does a similar job.

If you are unfamiliar with using this control, then please see the [Walkthrough: Arranging Controls on Windows Forms Using a TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4yc3e8c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more help. This page provides many useful examples and links to further examples... I'm sure that you will be able to work out what to do.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code..!!

```
<Window x:Class="SpiltWindow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">First</TextBlock>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Second</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Third</TextBlock>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Fourth</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer solves the problem posted in the question.